# DataContractSerializer with derived type not deserializing base type properties

Tags: c#, serialization

I used to have a class `JobData` that is serialized and deserialized using `DataContractSerializer`; I have since refactored some of the attributes of `JobData` into `BaseData` so they can be used in other derived classes. Now when I deserialize objects, only the attributes that remain in `JobData` are deserialized, and the ones in `BaseData` are not. It is important that I am able to deserialize files created before the refactoring was done.

I have tried using the constructor

```
DataContractSerializer Constructor (Type, IEnumerable<Type>)
```

to let it know about `BaseData`, and adding [`KnownType(typeof(BaseData))]` to the top of the `JobData` class, but nothing I have come across in other pages posted online seems to work.

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(JobData), new List<Type>{typeof(BaseData)});
JobData deserializedData = (JobData)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your properties on BaseData are not public? Because your code looks correct and even if you leave out DataContract and DataMembers on both classes the de/serialization will still work.

Comment: Unless you forgot to derive JobData from BaseData ;)

Answer (score 0):

Show your class definitions. I'm betting that you are missing an attribute.